# Access 2007 query

Tags: sql, ms-access

Below is the data I'm working with:

```
Location ID   Member ID   $1 Bill   $5 Bill   DATE       TIME
56789         000000000   2220      2000      4/1/2012   43337
56789         000000000   2221      2000      4/1/2012   62219
56789         000000000   2221      2000      4/1/2012   62220
56789         000123456   2226      2000      4/1/2012   63206
56789         000000000   2228      2001      4/1/2012   64438
```

I need a query to determine the dollar amount of each bill denomination received for each location, as well as the total dollar amount received for each location.

> Location ID 56789 received a total of $1 between the time (s) of 4:33:37 and 6:22:19 from Member ID 000000000.
>
> Location ID 56789 received a total of $5 between the time (s) of 6:22:20 and 6:32:06 from Member ID 000000000.
>
> Location ID 56789 received a total of $7 between the time (s) of 6:32:06 and 6:44:38 from Member ID 000123456.

The Total amount received for `Location ID 56789` for the date of `4/1/2012` is `$13`.

Any suggestions on how I would write a query to determine this ?

**EDIT (additional info)**

I also need to able to return `[Member ID] = 000123456 with a [$1 Bill] total count of 2`.

Example of desired result (per request):

```
Location ID  Member ID  $1 Bill Total  $5 Bill Total  DATE
  56789      000000000      5               0       4/1/2012
  56789      000123456      2               5       4/1/2012
```

Comment: Rather than saying what you "would conclude," how about a specific question you want to ask about your data, giving the input parameters you have and the output that you need?

Comment: Thanks for the follow ups. In the TIME column, 43337 (for example) represents 4:33:37 AM in the 24 hour format. The $1 bill and $5 bill fields combined incrementation represents a total of $13 (8 ones, from 2220 -2228 and one 5, 2000 -2001).

Comment: Date and Time are reserved words. Using them as field names is a sure path to problems. Spaces in field names suck too, and I would avoid a leading $ as well (but the last one is probably not justified).

Comment: Thanks. I didn't have access to the pre-formatted data at the time of my post, so what i posted was the post format Excel spreadsheet version.

Comment: I'm not certain. The data is from as400. I think the field type is timestamp.

Comment: Currently shows data type as "number".

Comment: I should also add that while my example is 5 rows, I'm actually working with 30,000 rows. I also tried creating two tables sorted on the same values and ran a query using [ID] -1. This gave me the correct total for the above example. However, when I had multiple different member ID's in succession, obviously, it broke.

Comment: one $5 and two $1's. That total was for the location, not member ID. Mistake in the example on my part. Corrected the example.

Comment: Ha. OK, I've managed to confuse myself now. My original example was correct. I'll correct it. Thanks for following up also.

Answer (score 1):

First I'd like to say I am glad I don't have to work with a database that has this kind of naming convention.

Open a new query and paste this into the SQL view

```
SELECT[location id], max([$1 bill])-min([$1 bill]) +( max([$5 bill])-min([$5 bill]))*5 as dailyTotal
FROM myTable
group by [location id],date
```

and it will write a query that groups the daily totals for each location. from there you can change the WHERE part of the query to limit it down to whatever is useful.

Good luck

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution! This gets me in the ballpark for sure.

Comment: I've ran into an additional issue. Should I update my original post or provide the additional info in the comment section? Not sure on the forum etiquette.

Comment: Kind of depends what the issue is and how much it changes the original questions I think.  I am not totally up on the etiquette myself.

Comment: Thanks. I just added it to the original.

Comment: It I understand your change correctly, just add [member id] to the group by clause and the select clause.

Comment: I tried that and I'm getting a zero (instead of 2). I believe that's due to the member ID only having one entry, using Min and Max isn't working as there's nothing to compare.